# Parse.com, Adding users to created roles

Tags: parse-platform, role, user-roles

I have a cloud code which creates two account roles when a user signs up. Below is the method

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("account", function(request) {
    var accountName = request.object.get("name");

    //create admin role
    var adminRoleACL = new Parse.ACL();
    adminRoleACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    var adminRole = new Parse.Role(accountName + "_Administrator", adminRoleACL);
    adminRole.save() ; 

    //create user role
    var userRoleACL = new Parse.ACL();
    userRoleACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    var userRole = new Parse.Role(accountName + "_User", userRoleACL);
    userRole.save();
});
```

Now what i wanted to achieve was to add the user which just signed up to these two roles. But unfortunately i saw that in cloud code i can't get the current user. 
So what i did was to add the users in the role after the roles are created from the client side. Below is the code for the same. The code executes fine and i did not see any error, however i did not see the users being added to the roles in the data browser. Any idea why is this happening? Am i missing something. I would be really thankful for all your help.

```
user.signUp(null, {
    success : function(user) {
        var currentUser = Parse.User.current();

        var accountName = account.get("name");

        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
        query.contains("name", accountName);

        query.find({
            success : function(roles) {
                if (!roles) {
                    alert("No roles for " + accountName + " were found");
                } else {
                    for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
                        //add the user for admin role
                        //TODO: this needs to be done only once for the account owner
                        if (roles[i].get("name").search(USER_TYPE.ADMIN) >= 0) {
                            roles[i].getUsers().add(currentUser);
                        }

                        //add the user for user role
                        if (roles[i].get("name").search(USER_TYPE.USER) >= 0) {
                            roles[i].getUsers().add(currentUser);
                        }
                        var saved = roles[i].save();
                    }
                    alert("User was added into roles");
                }
            },
            error : function(error) {
                alert("Could not add users to the account " + accountName + " error: " + error.message);
            }
        });

        alert("User created successfully");
    },
    error : function(user, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

thanks for the help. I go it done by using a cloud code like this

1. Create the roles while creating the account.

   ```
   Parse.Cloud.afterSave("account", function(request) {

       var accountName = request.object.get("name");
       //create admin role
       var adminRoleACL = new Parse.ACL();
       adminRoleACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
       adminRoleACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
       var adminRole = new Parse.Role(accountName + "_Administrator", adminRoleACL);
       adminRole.save();

       //create user role
       var userRoleACL = new Parse.ACL();
       userRoleACL.setPublicReadAccess(false);
       userRoleACL.setPublicWriteAccess(false);
       var userRole = new Parse.Role(accountName + "_User", userRoleACL);
       userRole.save();
   });
   ```
2. Then add the users to the created role

   ```
   Parse.Cloud.define("addUsersToRole", function(request, response) {

       Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
       var currentUser = request.user;
       var accountName = request.params.accountname;
       var isAdmin = request.params.admin;

       var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);
       query.contains("name", accountName);
       query.find({
           success : function(roles) {
               console.log("roles: " + roles.length);
               for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {

                   if ( isAdmin = false && roles[i].get("name").search("_Administrator") >= 0)
                       continue;

                   roles[i].getUsers().add(currentUser);
                   roles[i].save();
               }
               response.success();
           },
           error : function(error) {
               response.error("error adding to admin role " + error);
           }
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Actually you can access the user that is performing the request, check the [Cloud Code Documentation](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-calling) for more details.

In particular, what you want is to look at `request.user`:

```
var currentUser = request.user;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The documentation for request.user says this

    user - The Parse.User that is making the request. This will not be set if there was no logged-in user.

I am trying to do add the users when we do signup, so the user is not logged in and hence is null. So i think this can only be done by calling another cloud function which does this after logging in

Comment: Who is saving the "account" object? The user saving that will be exposed as the `request.user` in Cloud Code.