# Add a user with particular role, ex: admin or normal user

Tags: php, laravel, parse-platform, roles

I am using **PHP(laravel)**. I want to add role with each user I add.

How can I achieve it?

```
$postData->__set('roles',$postData->dataType('relation',array('Role','_user')));
```

I used something like this, but it is not proper.

I am able to save users to the user table in parse, but I have two roles in the roles table, **admin and user**(normal user). I need to add my user one among this. '**Relation**' is a datatype in parse.com, using that is there some way to achieve it.

Comment: Tell about `$postData->__set` where did it come from ?

Comment: Thanks for the response, set is just set variable function in parseUser.php library and $postData is parseUser object for adding user. Like the way i added pointer, for joining two tables. So i tried this way.

Comment: Is there any documentation for this `Parse php` library ?

Comment: https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library , this all i have.

Comment: I got a small module in laravel also, https://github.com/linuxjuggler/laravel-and-parse-book . This is someone else created, and using these to references i got the idea behind parse.com. Right now user and role creating problem.

Comment: I didn't find any `datatype` as `relation`.

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/linuxjuggler/laravel-and-parse-book/blob/master/www/laravel/app/libraries/parse/parse.php) there is no such `datatype` in this method.

Comment: Ya off course nothing is there, but in parse backend they have relation, pointer etc. datatypes. Did you visit parse.com dashboard ? There after creating classname(table) , if you want to add columns(+col) you can see data type lists. So relation is parse.com datatype and it is some how realting already existing User and Role tables.

Comment: Yes, you are right but I'm not sure about the `php` library, just heard now, so kind of confused how it works, but if i can get any idea I'll post and in the mean time you should post more related code so others can get a clean idea that you are doing. All the best -)

Comment: Thanks Sheikh Heera. I am searching for the related stuffs, i got a cloud code here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18970416/parse-com-adding-users-to-created-roles?rq=1 . Dont know how to convert it to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Just use CodeCloud and call the Cloud Function using the Parse.com PHP Library.

This function in JavaScript add an array of User's ObjectId to a role with a Name

```
// Add array of user ids to role with defined name

Parse.Cloud.define('addUsersToRole', function(request, response) {
    // Params
    var userIds = request.params.users;
    var roleName = request.params.role;

    // Underscore
    var _ = require('underscore');

    // Master Key
    // skip ACL check
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    // new role query        
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);

    // get the role with given name
    query.equalTo('name', roleName);

    // get the first result using promises
    query.first().then(function(role){
        if(role) {

            var userRelation = role.relation('users');

            _.each(userIds, function(userId) {
                // create a new user object
                var user = new Parse.User();

                // assign the id
                user.id = userId;

                // add it to the role user relation
                userRelation.add(user);

                // a simple user counter
                role.increment('userCount');
            });

            // save the role      
            role.save().then(function(){
                response.success();
            });


        } else {
            response.error('No Role found with Name ' + roleName);
        }
    });

});
```

Then using the PHP Parse Library call the function

```
<?php
    // https://github.com/apotropaic/parse.com-php-library/blob/master/parseCloud.php

    // Adding the possibility to run parse cloud code functions
    $cloud = new parseCloud("addUsersToRole");

    // Setting the params

    $cloud->__set('users',array('oviajjs3', 'CskkO33d', 'Casi33Jn'));

    $cloud->__set('role','admin');

    // Running the cloud function
    $result = $cloud->run();
?>
```